# Cannot fill-in rootUri and rootPath fields in model configuration for monaco-editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I am setting a monaco language client for lsp server. I need to configure rootUri and rootPath fields. However, I create an editor via the following code. I have a problem that `rootUri` and `rootPath` fields are equal to null, though I tried to use different Uri (file, parsing of url). Nothing of that worked.

```
const uri = Uri.file('/home/test.cpp');
const editor = monaco.editor.create(this.$refs.editor, {
                model: monaco.editor.createModel(this.code, 'cpp', uri),
                glyphMargin: true,
                lightbulb: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                showUnused: true,
                tabCompletion: true,
            });
            MonacoServices.install(editor);
```

Please give some information how I am able to change the values of `rootUri` and `rootPath` fields.

Comment: Found out - to add in clientOptions in MonacoLanguageClient constructor a workspaceFolder: { uri }.